# How can I create a new user—with Profile 2 fields—programmatically?

Tags: 7, users

I am writing a module where I need to create a new user and save his profile fields using Profile 2.

This is the code I'm using, but it's not working:

```
$edit = array(
  'name' => $submission->data[1]['value'][0],
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'mail' => $email,
  'init' => $email,
  'status' => 1,
  'roles' => $role_id,
  'profile_first_name' => $submission->data[1]['value'][0],
  'profile_surname' => 'ag',
  'profile_email' => $email,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
);

$new_user = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit/*,'customer_profile'*/);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears someone else decided to rewrite your question to something completely different than what you originally asked, so I apologize for answering to that question instead of what you really wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I load the profile object:

```
$profile = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, '<role type here>');
```

Then I edit the $profile object.

I have a Rules component that saves the profile object. I forget why I have the rule but I remember that it requires quite a bit of code and database queries to get it right.

I set the Rules component to take the $profile object as an argument / parameter and invoke it like this.

```
    rules_invoke_component('rules_machine_name_this_is_the_component_url_too', $profile);
```

Comment: - I am creating the user, but when i create the user its automatically login the user. How to prevent this ?

Comment: Might be you are using user_load() function, I had also face same issue.