# Programatically create field collection into Profile2 on new user creation

Tags: 7, users, entities

I've set up my own custom multi-step registration form, because I just couldn't find a way of making anything out there do what I want. I've found other questions on here [like this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39210/how-to-add-profile2-field-data-to-a-programatically-created-user) and [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18387/how-can-i-create-a-new-userwith-profile-2-fieldsprogrammatically) which have basically got me 95% there. My main problem now is that I've got a series of field collections in my Profile2 fields, and I just can't seem to find out what my code needs to be in order to get it done properly.

*At this point in the code I've created a new user ($user), and their profile2 ($profile2) and I'm trying to format my fields from my form so that I can throw them all into the $profile2 object.

field_activities

- field_start_year
- field_end_year
- field_text

My code so far is:

```
$field_collection = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_activities'));
$field_collection->setHostEntity('profile', $profile2);
$field_collection->field_start_year = $entry['start_year'];
$field_collection->field_end_year = $entry['end_year'];
$field_collection->field_text = $entry['text'];
$field_collection->save(FALSE);
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `setHostEntity()` on a non-object

Which would make more sense to me if `$profile2` wasn't an object, but it is.

I've got too many unknowns to figure this out at the moment, is it the right code? can I build a create a field collection item on a newly created profile2 object? do I populate all the fields of the profile object first, and then once it's saved, then add the field collections, etc.

Comment: I'd guess you need to save the profile2 object before using it as a host entity, and also the entity type is `profile2`, not `profile`, so I would guess `setHostEntity('profile', $profile2);` needs to be `setHostEntity('profile2', $profile2);` The error you're getting is saying that `$field_collection` is not an object, it doesn't mention the `$profile2` variable

Comment: Ok, thanks for this, I wasn't sure what my entity type was 'profile' or 'profile2'. I'll have a go at setting up my profile and then using it as the host, see how I get on

Comment: That comment has really helped, it made me realise where the problem lay, it's very nearly working now, it's not throwing back any errors, but it doesn't appear to actually be saving anything. Since my field collection has unlimited values, I've got this function looping through each returned answer in the form, and whilst it appears to output each new field collection entity fully filled, it doesn't get written to the profile2 information, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `setHostEntity()` on a non-object

The error means that you are trying to call `setHostEntity()` method on a **non-object**, in other words the `$field_collection` is **not** an object (NULL probably).

So please check one line before, which is:

```
$field_collection = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_activities'));
```

So basically you are trying to load `field_activities` field collection, but it is not there, therefore your `$field_collection` is `FALSE` as per [entity_create  API](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_create/7):

> Return value: A new instance of the entity type or `FALSE` if there is no information for the given entity type.

Therefore please make sure your `field_activities` exists as field collection (e.g. at `/admin/structure/field-collections`), or add additional failing scenario to your code, so when `$field_collection` is `FALSE`, do not execute further code.

For valid examples using field collections, check: [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) page.

Comment: I agree with you . vote up